# vtkImageData to DcmDataset

Tags: c++, vtk

I hold a volume image in a vtkImageData and need to convert it to DcmDataset (DCMTK). I know that I need to set general DICOM tags like patient data to the data set. That's not the problem.
Especially I'm interested in putting the pixel data to DcmDataset. Does anybody know an example or can explain how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [DCMTK FAQ](http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=56):

> Is there a tool that converts common graphic formats like PGM/PPM,
>   PNG, TIFF, JPEG or BMP to DICOM?
>        No, unfortunately, there is no such tool in DCMTK. Currently, you have to write your own little program for that purpose.
>        The following code snippet from the toolkit's documentation could be a starting point:

```
char uid[100];
DcmFileFormat fileformat;
DcmDataset *dataset = fileformat.getDataset();
dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_SOPClassUID, UID_SecondaryCaptureImageStorage);
dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_SOPInstanceUID, dcmGenerateUniqueIdentifier(uid, SITE_INSTANCE_UID_ROOT));
dataset->putAndInsertString(DCM_PatientsName, "Doe^John");
/* ... */
dataset->putAndInsertUint8Array(DCM_PixelData, pixelData, pixelLength);
OFCondition status = fileformat.saveFile("test.dcm", EXS_LittleEndianExplicit);
if (status.bad())
  cerr << "Error: cannot write DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")" << endl;
```

> The current snapshot of the DCMTK (> version 3.5.4) contains a new
>   command line tool "img2dcm" that allows for converting JPEG images to
>   certain DICOM image SOP classes.

I would perhaps look first at the source code for **img2dcm** ([documented here](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-dcmrt/img2dcm.html)) to see the general process and then post back with any specific questions. IMHO, DCMTK is very powerful but extremely difficult to understand.